# AJAX и подход MVC PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, mvc

В учебных целях пишу веб-ресурс **(не являюсь профессионалом в данной сфере)**. Принцип MVC понятен, но когда попытался внедрить в него Ajax запрос - сломал голову.
Непосредственно проблема: на странице с карточками продуктов пытаюсь сделать кнопку "Показать еще". По нажатию на нее посылаю POST запрос который должен вернуть HTML вьюшки, но возвращается HTML всей отрисованной страницы.
В чем проблема?

**Роут:**

```
'products/ajax' => 'products/ajax'
```

**Ajax запрос:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#load-more").click(function() {
        $.post("ajax", 
               {page: 1},
               function (data) {
                    $("#load-more").html(data);
               }
        ); 
    }); 
});
```

**Контроллер:**

```
class ProductsController extends Controller {
    public function actionAjax($params = null) {
        $paramsArray = array(
            'content' => 'products/ajax.php',
        );

        $this -> view -> display($paramsArray);
    }
}
```

**Вид (находится в products/ajax.php):**

```
<div>Привет!</div>
```

Такой вид сделал для теста, полную страницу сверстаю в будущем.

**Кнопка до нажатия:**

[image: Кнопка до нажатия]

**Кнопка после нажатия:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: обычно вьюшки внедряются в основной layout, который уже содержит, шапку/подвал, всякие там менюшки и прочее. Каким образом рендерится вьюшка у вас? Вы вообще взяли какой-то фреймворк,  или это самопис? Общая суть в том, что layout при таком вызове инклудить не надо. Иногда называется что-нибудь вроде `renderPartial`

Comment: @teran, да, у меня есть **template** в который я отправляю путь до нужной вьюшки. Эту работу я пишу вручную, так как это условие задания. А вот код **template**: `<?php class View { public function display($paramsArray) { if (isset($paramsArray['template'])) { require_once('application/views/'.$paramsArray['template']); } else { require_once('application/views/products/ajax.php'); } } } ?>`  
Статичный путь прописан исключительно ради проверки работоспособности

Comment: Лучше всего сделать дополнительный макет (layout) сайта специально для ajax-запросов, в котором не будет стандартных шапки и подвала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал вывод из всей этой ситуации: **устал - иди отдыхай!**
При написании роутов допустил ошибку:

```
// Продукты
'products/(.+)' => 'products/index/$1',
'products/ajax' => 'products/ajax',
```

Как вы понимаете данные регулярные выражения подобны друг другу и когда я пытался запустить ajax запрос получал данные этих двух страниц.
Соответственно изменил на следующие:

```
// Продукты
'products/([a-z_]{1,})' => 'products/index/$1',
'products/ajax/display_more' => 'products/ajax',
```

Правда в ответе остались подключения css и js файлов, но думаю это мне не помешает.
Всем спасибо за ваши ответы!)

Comment: а не достаточно было их местами поменять?